# Make parent thread wait till child thread finishes in VC

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

According to MSDN:

The `WaitForSingleObject` function can wait for the following objects:

```
Change notification
Console input
Event
Memory resource notification
Mutex
Process
Semaphore
Thread
Waitable timer
```

Then we can use `WaitForSingleObject` to make the parent-thread wait for child ones.

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE h_child_thread = CreateThread(0,0, child, 0,0,0); //create a thread in VC

    WaitForSingleObject(h_child_thread, INFINITE); //So, parent-thread will wait

    return 0;

}
```

**Question**

1. Is there any other way to make parent-thread wait for child ones in VC or Windows?
2. I don't quite understand the usage of `WaitForSingleObject` here, does it mean that **the thread's handle will be available when the thread terminates**?

Answer (score 1):

for the first queation - yes. The method commonly used here is "Join". the usage is language dependant.

In .NET C++ you can use the Thread's Join method. this is from the msdn:

```
Thread* newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(0, Test::Work));
newThread->Start();

if(newThread->Join(waitTime + waitTime))
{
    Console::WriteLine(S"New thread terminated.");
}
else
{
    Console::WriteLine(S"Join timed out.");
}
```

Secondly, the thread is terminated when when you are signaled with "WaitForSingleObject" but the handle is still valid (for a terminated thread). So you still need to explicitly close the handle with CloseHandle.

Comment: while I agree with your post in essence, you should note that your code snippet is not C++, the Thread class that you used in your example is part of the .NET class library, so it can only be used in the .NET family of languages.

Comment: Correct, I am using the fact that the user mentioned this is a windows application. but I will add this to the answer

Answer (score 1):

1. You can establish communication between threads in multiple ways and the terminating thread may somehow signal its waiting thread. It could be as simple as writing some special value to a shared memory location that the waiting thread can check. But this won't guarantee that the terminating thread has terminated when the waiting thread sees the special value (ordering/race conditions) or that the terminating thread terminates shortly after that (it can just hang or block on something) and it won't guarantee that the special value gets ever set before the terminating thread actually terminates (the thread can crash). WaitForSingleObject (and its companion WaitForMultipleObjects) is a sure way to know of a thread termination when it occurs. Just use it.
2. The handle will still be available in the sense that its value won't be gone. But it is practically useless after the thread has terminated, except you need this handle to get the thread exit code. And you still need to close the handle in the end. That is unless you're OK with handle/memory leaks.

Comment: regarding #2, the handle is not useless, you use it to obtain the return code from the thread that ended, if that is of use to your application.